# In a Terminal profile, how can I set it to cd right after ssh connects?

Tags: macos, bash, ssh, terminal

I'm on OS X, using Terminal (bash) to connect to my web server. I'd like to set up the Profile so that it opens to a specific subdirectory after ssh connects.I don't always want to start in this directory — this profile is meant for managing a specific area of the server.

Right now I have the profile set up in the Terminal Preferences > Profile > Shell > Startup > Run command: `ssh me@server.com; cd sub/folders/`

Of course, ssh connects and the second command never runs. Any way to do this within a Terminal profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @rickfillion:

```
ssh -t me@server.com "cd sub/folders/; bash -l"
```

Answer (score 0):

ssh user@ip  cd /path/to/dir   SHOULD do it fine OR  set it in the ssh_config file for that connection even:

Comment: Your first answer runs the command then exits the ssh connection immediately. If I understand your second, it would run it every time I connect, which I don't want (as stated in my question). Thanks, though.

Comment: I was assuming you wanted every time if not use rickfillion's response